# Not able to create a new folder in device's Documents folder even after giving runtime permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-permissions

Asking this questions after trying a lot. I have checked a lot ob blogs and questions.

When I'm trying to create a new folder in the device's doucments folder, its not creating the folder even after giving all permissions including runtime permissions.

This is my code to create the new folder -

```
var path = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS))
        var directory = path.absolutePath + "/justCheck"

        var file = File(directory)
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile()
        }
```

I'm checking on Android device with marshmallow OS. This is my permissions in Manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, I have authorized the runtime permissions.

Am I doing anything wrong ? Why is the older not getting created ?

Answer (score 1):

You've to create a folder not a file:

```
file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Thanks. and what if i want to create an empty document like name.txt ?

Comment: Mate make an effort ... anyhow I use this for creating files under the newly created dir _File(File dir, String name) {_

Comment: its not getting created, thats why i asked a question. there is something im missing out. its clearly written on my question about what i have tried. may be you didn't read my question properly.

Comment: For me it works. Try this first as abolute path _mAppCtx.getFilesDir() + "/justCheck"_ because that doesn't requires any special permission. If that works then you're clearly doing something wrong in how you handle the permissions